# Change button visibility with savedInstanceState

Tags: android, button, visibility

I've got a strange problem here. Here is my fragment's onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_question, container, false);

    btnAnswerA = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerA);
    btnAnswerB = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerB);
    btnAnswerC = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerC);
    btnAnswerD = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerD);

    btnAnswerA.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswerB.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswerC.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswerD.setOnClickListener(this);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        btnAnswerA.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(ANS_A_ENABLED_KEY));
        btnAnswerB.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(ANS_B_ENABLED_KEY));
        btnAnswerC.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(ANS_C_ENABLED_KEY));
        btnAnswerD.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(ANS_D_ENABLED_KEY));
    }

    return view;
}
```

and onSaveInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putInt(ANS_A_ENABLED_KEY, btnAnswerA.getVisibility());
    outState.putInt(ANS_B_ENABLED_KEY, btnAnswerB.getVisibility());
    outState.putInt(ANS_C_ENABLED_KEY, btnAnswerC.getVisibility());
    outState.putInt(ANS_D_ENABLED_KEY, btnAnswerD.getVisibility());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Now what's the problem: in the (savedInstanceState != null) block, the visibility of the buttons doesn't change at all. Even if I write manually - btnAnswerA.setVisibility(4) - it doesn't execute. It does execute Log commands though, with which I see that savedInstanceState contains the needed values. Why I am doing this: I need to save the buttons' state when user rotates the screen.

If you have any ideas why does it happen and how to fix it, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Where else is the View visibility set? I would try something like changing the background image as well, to see if maybe your visibility changes are being overridden somewhere.

Comment: In one method I hide 2 of the buttons. Anyway, I saw my mistake - the fragment loads twice: the first time it does it's job, but the second doesn't have savedInstanceState, so... yeah. Now I do check from the activity: if the fragment is not null, I don't load another one. Thank you for the suggestions!